# Program stuck at ProgressDialog

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using Android Studio and Firebase. The code is not creating the new user when I run emulator. The program gets stuck at `progressDialog` "Registering please wait". I can manually add users in Firebase. I've enabled the email/password `auth` in Firebase console but still prob exists

This is **MainActivity.java** file.

```
package com.example.application.firebaseauthdemo;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //defining view objects
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonSignup;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    //defining firebaseauth object
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing firebase auth object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //initializing views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        //attaching listener to button
        buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void registerUser(){

        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            //display some message here
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //calling register method on click
        registerUser();
    }
}
```

(2) *Project(build.gradle)* file..I've already added classpath.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

(3)  *App(**build.gradle**)* file...Here,I've added all the firebase dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
        {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig
            {
        applicationId "com.example.application.firebaseauthdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've added all the required dependencies. Plus, added the same classpath as it was in Firebase. Also, I cleaned the project and `rebuild` it. But still the problem can't be solved. Also,I've enabled the Email/Password Authentication in the Firebase console. Still the app keeps on getting stuck at the `progressDialog` and users can't be registered in the Firebase `auth`.

Comment: @UltimateDevil: please don't add inline code formatting to things that are not code. Firebase is just a brand and proper noun, so it gets a capital letter, and that's it. Thanks.

Comment: Shagun, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok Sir, @halfer this mistake will not be in Future again

Answer (score 0):

You should create AsyncTask for loaded work.

**For Example:**

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            //display some message here
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                super.onPostExecute(o);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };
        asyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: is it giving run time exception?

Comment: no..it isn't giving any error or exception.It is just that users are not being added to the firebase auth.The progressDialog is just showing "Registering please wait"..And no action is taking place after that.

Comment: firebase listeners are asynchronous listeners, you don't need to wrap them with an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an ***addOnFailureListener*** to check what is failing, because the ***addOnCompleteListener*** is never called.

```
//creating a new user
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    // YOUR CODE
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```